# Android Chinese characters in WebView

Tags: android, character-encoding, webview, cjk

I have a html code which I saved in `home.txt` file and placed it raw folder. Now I want to display the same in a `WebView`. I used the following code for it.

```
homeWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.homeWebview);
InputStream fileStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.home); 
int fileLen = fileStream.available();

// Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer. 
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileLen]; 
fileStream.read(fileBuffer);

fileStream.close();  
displayText = new String(fileBuffer);

//Display content.          
homeWebview.loadData(displayText, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

It is working fine. Now I have to display some Chinese characters in the html. I added the Chinese character in home.txt. Here it is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Language</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: HelveticaExt-normal, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin:0;font-size:20px;color:#000000;}
.mainWrapper {margin:0;}
p {margin: 10px;}
p.bodytext {margin: 0 10px 20px;}
.headerText { background:#eeeeee; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fefefe), to(#e0e0e0));border-top: 2px solid #000000;padding-bottom:7px;}
.headerText p {margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;}
a {color:#324f85;text-decoration:underline;}
.headerbar {border-top:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;height:34px;font-family:HelveticaExt-bold, Helvetica, Sans-serif;color:#fff;font-size:18px;padding-left:10px;line-height:34px;margin:0;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#494e4f), to(#787a7c));
}
.navigationList {list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
.navigationList li {height:60px;border-bottom:2px solid #e0e0e0;background-position:10px center;background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-left:60px;line-height:28px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="headerText">
        <p欢迎您到泰国语言主持人！<a href="http://www.test.com">www.test.com</a> 欲了解更多信息！</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now it is displaying the common characters well, but all the Chinese char is showing as unknown char. What is the prob in my code?

Comment: Why do you have `<p` instead of `<p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home.txt file was not in UTF-8 encoded, I open it in notepad++ and change the encoding. Now it is showing properly.

Answer (score 5):

use `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL (null, text,  "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in this line:

```
displayText = new String(fileBuffer);
```

You should change to

```
displayText = new String(fileBuffer, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have just tried it...but its not working. Its giving same output.