# why Chinese characters are not displayed correctly inside webView when trying to load an html string inside

Tags: android, html, url, webview

Using `webView.loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)` on Android for displaying an html content inside a `webView` won't show the Chinese characters correctly. Using `loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)` with null values for `"baseUrl"` and `"historyUrl"` will solve the problem. Is there for such behavior?

```
webView.loadData: Does not display the Chinese characters correctly
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL: Displays the Chinese characters correctly`
```

---

```
webView.loadData("html content containing Chinese characters", "text/html", "UTF-8"); //does not work
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "html content containing Chinese characters", "text/html", "UTF-8", null); //works
```

Answer (score 0):

Habe a look here :
[Android Chinese characters in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196887/android-chinese-characters-in-webview)

Be sure the content of the website is UTF-8 / same enconding you use, too.

Comment: The encoding is actually the same in both. Still the method that works `loadDataWithBaseURL` without passing a URL instead of `loadData`